# Vue: How to set data from within an "inner" function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm using Vue and Axios to display a progress bar. `uploadProgress` is a data key in my Vue instance. When I try to set it using an inner function, it just says its undefined. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
someVueMethod() {
  this.uploadProgress = 0 // this works

  let config = { 
    onUploadProgress(progress) {
      // this doesn't work, error says uploadProgress is undefined
      this.uploadProgress += progress.loaded / progress.total
    }
  }
  axios.put(url, file, config).then(res => {
    // handle the response
  })
}
```

How can I set `uploadProgress` from within that inner function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `uploadProgress` to the context of the function `someVueMethod`, but are trying to access it in the context of the function `onUploadProgress`. You need to use the original context like this.

```
someVueMethod() {
  var self = this; //store the context of someVueMethod
  this.uploadProgress = 0 // this works

  let config = { 
    onUploadProgress(progress) {
      // use the original context using self
      self.uploadProgress += progress.loaded / progress.total
    }
  }
  axios.put(url, file, config).then(res => {
    // handle the response
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I tried several similar approaches, trying to get the context in there, and couldn't quite get it. This worked perfectly. Thanks!