# passing function as prop in vuejs

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, scope, vue-props

So i am creating a base "TableComponent", with selectable rows etc. This TableComponent takes a prop called "buttons". 
The TableComponent expects the buttons to be an array of objects like this:

```
buttons: [{
    label: 'Manage Themes',
    click: () => {
        if(this.selectedRows.length) {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'ManagePageOptions', query: { concernable_type: this.type, concernable_ids: this.selectedRows.map(row => row.id).join(',') }});
        } else {
            alert('Please select 1 or more company or user');
        }
    }
}]
```

And so in the table component, a row of buttons is created based on what is passed like so:

```
<b-button v-for="button in this.buttons" @click="button.click" :key="button.label"> {{ button.label }} </b-button>
```

Problem is that in the buttons click function, "this" refers to the parent component, and so i don't have access to the selected rows etc.

**EDIT:**
I have found that just passing "this" to the click function solves it. Not sure if it is wise though.

```
buttons = [{
    label: 'Manage Pages',
    click: (vm) => {
        if(vm.selectedRows.length) {
            vm.$router.push({ name: 'ManagePageOptions', query: { concernable_type: vm.type, concernable_ids: vm.selectedRows.map(row => row.id).join(',') }});
        } else {
          alert(Lang('Please select 1 or more company or user'))
        }
    }
}];
```

TableComponent data:

```
data() {
    return {
      selectedRows: [],
      m_this: this,
    };
  },
```

_

```
<b-button v-for="button in this.buttons" @click="button.click(m_this)" :key="button.label"> {{ button.label }} </b-button>
```

Comment: Try adding using `@click=button.click($event)`, and make use of a variable in the `click: (obj) => {}` and then check what this gives you

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. In that case, the button should be emitting a `click` event (or any name of your choice). The consuming parent, `TableComponent`, will then listen to this VueJS event using the `v-on` or `@` shorthand, and decide how to handle it thereafter.

Comment: Agree with @Terry, it's generally not advised to pass methods as props, having the child emit an event is the prescribed way

Comment: Defining the buttons using a scoped slot may also be an option that avoids this problem altogether. If you really want to stick with your current approach then I suggest passing suitable arguments to `click` rather than trying to grab them via `this`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with comments that there are better ways to do this, scoped slots is probably the best....

But, if you really want to pass functions like that you need:

1. Change handler definition from `click: () => {}` to `click: function() {}` - reason is that `this` [works completely different in arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and as a result `this` is bound to the parent Vue component
2. When passing handler into button component (inside `TableComponent` template), bind the handler to `this` of your `TableComponent` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391499/381282)